# Timestring turns from AM to PM

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, time

I am working with timestring which gets data from my sql server, but the problem is that when it tries to convert the hours it turns to 02, 03 not 14 or 15. But when I do `var_dump($timeString);` It shows correct.

[image]

when I do `var_dump($hours);` it shows:

[image]

Code:

```
        $timeString = $r['time'];
        $hours = $timeString->format('h');
        $minutes = $timeString->format('m');
        $seconds = $timeString->format('s');

        //var_dump($timeString);
        //var_dump($hours);
```

Comment: Try `H` instead of `h`

Comment: Solved the problem with G - http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Comment: Good luck using `m` for minutes.

Answer (score 0):

In the date format `m` is month, use `i` for minutes and `H` instead of `h` to get 24 hour time:

```
    $timeString = $r['time'];
    $hours   = $timeString->format('H');
    $minutes = $timeString->format('i');
    $seconds = $timeString->format('s');
```